# Inference about sample means from sample proportions

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Given proportions $p_1$ and $p_2$ for samples of size $n_1$ and $n_2$ is the distribution of differences in sample means $n_1p_1$ and $n_1p_2$ normally distributed or $t$-distributed?

I am unsure because I "know"--in the sense of "statistics text books say"--that differences in proportions are normally distributed and differences in means are $t$-distributed.

I understand that differences in proportions are normally distributed because the individual events are Bernoulli-distributed--as are all categorical random variable put into the categories $A$ and ~$A$--and therefore binomially distributed in aggregate. This makes differences in proportions asymptotically normal.

I am less certain as to exactly why the difference in sample means are $t$-distributed, except that the sample variances are also normally distributed, meaning that the sample variance can underestimate or overestimate the population variance.

---

I used the wrong symbols when asking the question. $p_1$ and $p_2$ are supposed to be the sample proportions $\hat{p}_1$ and $\hat{p}_2$. Thus, I am interested in the distribution of the difference in **sample** means $n_1\hat{p}_1$ and $n_2\hat{p}_2$.

Comment: It does not seem to me that comparing $n_1p_1$ to $n_2p_2$ is a useful test.

Suppose $n_1=100$, $n_2=200$, and $p_1=p_2=0.5$. Then comparing $n_1p_1=50$ to $n_2p_2=100$ doesn't give us any useful information. 

However, when comparing means, we use a $t$-distribution because we are estimating two parameters; the mean and variance. When estimating proportions, we only have one parameter to estimate. If we know $p$, which is considered the population mean, then we know the variance since this is just $p(1-p)$. The sample proportion $\hat{p}$ gives us estimates of both the mean and variance.